# Importing modules I do not use

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller keeps importing scipy when I exclude it through `exclude module`. That did not work.

I am using Miniconda on Windows. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like pyinstaller should include a FAQ page that states...

**Do not** use **Anaconda/Miniconda**, use virtual environment or 
default python

**…**